# if there is a town where 4.5 people on average get frostbites every year,

Tags: probability

if there is a town where 4.5 people on average get frostbites every year, find the probability that in the next 3 years, there will be at least one year with 3 or more people with frostbites

we are asked to identify the type of distribution this is - and for extra credit, solve it

I think it is negative binomial distribution since we are asked to find a certain amount of successes, but I can't figure out how to solve it, since I tried using the neg. bin. distribution formula but how do I calculate the probability?

Comment: You can assume about any distribution you want... You should clarify your constraints, for example should $P(X=X_0-d) = P(X=X_0+d)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Poisson distribution, as it is discrete and non-negative.

You know the expected value. Per year distribution can be calculated.

Etc.